# Save small data in application

Tags: c#

I want to save some small pieces of information which change simultaneously every second. But the problem is where I can save it?

I tried to save in application setting & xml file tab. But when applications quit all data get corrupted. Because it won't save. The same issues like when the electricity went out, normal problem in my country. This is also corrupt stored information.

I am wondering to save in database but its quite small information and I don't think to use whole database for it.

Comment: "But when applications quit all data get corrupted." Sounds like you should be able to fix this issue without switching to something else.

Comment: How much data are we talking about?  SQLite is a relatively small database, and because it has transactional capabilities, it will protect your data from being corrupted.

Comment: SQLite or use two files

Comment: make a text file and write the variable value to it

Comment: I do the same with xml but its get corrupt most of time and show binary with 0 all the way!

Comment: So both application settings **and** xml files get "corrupted"?  Sounds more like you are doing something incorrectly.  Can you provide more details on the data you are saving and give us some example code where you write and read it?...

Comment: @Idle_Mind I used xml document save function! I guess this is a good way to save data!

Answer (score 8):

Use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) as a local storage database. You can save the data using [Transaction](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html). Using transaction can help you get rid of data corruption problem.

Comment: Yes I am considering to use it, But seriously I just need to store 2 variables! and I don't like to use DB for it!

Comment: @Capripio, yeah it would may be an overkill, but I thought your main problem is data corruption, SQLite would give you transaction, that will enable you in saving all or nothing, thus saving you from data corruption.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use SQL Express. It is integrated into VS environment so it's very easy to setup in your project. It is simply a file-based version of SQL you can add to your project and then design through Visual Studio. Step-by-step instructions are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: If you go the Microsoft route, you should use SQL Server Compact, as it is a file-based solution like SQLite.  SQL Server proper is a pain in the ass from an installation standpoint.

Comment: Here's a good comparison of Express vs. Compact. [link](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html) @RobertHarvey

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention in a comment that you're only storing 2 variables, a database is probably an overkill. Instead create a class that will round-robin write to two separate files, always picking the older one of the files to write to, as long as the newer one is valid. That way if one of the files gets corrupt, you can revert to the older "version" based on file modified timestamp. You can pick your favorite file format and verify when loading that the file is not corrupt. Your read/write logic can be like follows:

Reads:

1. Read the newer file.
2. If corrupt, read the older file.

Writes:

1. Read the newer file. If corrupt, overwrite it. This is to make sure you don't overwrite the old one when the new one was already corrupt, ending with two corrupt files.
2. If not corrupt, overwrite the older file. This makes sure if you corrupt the older file, you still have the newer file's values.